# Tried to install Mayavi package on Mac for python 3.7

Tags: python, macos, installation, anaconda, mayavi

When I tried to install Mayavi package on my anaconda, I got the error showed in the picture. I have no clue how to deal with this.

[image: error code]

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**. Also helpful if you give some details e.g. what was the command you executed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the future, please try searching the error first. In this case a solution can be found at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381/252736. I.e., you need to install xcode commandline tools.

Comment: I have solved the problem with using Conda install rather than pip install